# Filemanager with tinymce laravel showing same page when browsing

Tags: php, laravel-5, tinymce, file-manager

I am trying to use TinyMCE with UniSharp filemanager.

Whenever I click on the browse button of filemanager it opens my webpage (screenshot).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Laravel 5.4, and fixed this when I came across it by updating the `'middlewares'` value in `lfm.php` to the following:

`'middlewares' => ['web', 'auth']`

If you don't have the `lfm.php` file, you need to export the config by running the following as described in Step 3 of the installation at http://unisharp.github.io/laravel-filemanager/installation

`php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lfm_config`